# Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I know this question probably has been asked before but I'm a beginner to templates, and here is my code,

HeaderFile.h

```
class Identity  {
    public:    
        template <typename T>
        T getFamilyMembers() {
            if(1) {
              return false;
            }
            std::string whatever = "Test";
            return whatever;
        }
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "HeaderFile.h"

int main() {
  Identity id;
  std::cout << id.getFamilyMembers() << "\n";
}
```

Compiler issue two errors,

```
Main.cpp:25:10: error: no matching member function for call to 'getFamilyMembers'
      id.getFamilyMembers();
      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
HeaderFile.h:22:11: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
        T getFamilyMembers() {
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] Also, `getFamilyMembers` can't return a `bool` and a `string`. Also, the return type of a function can't be deduced, only parameters can.

Comment: @cigien Apologize, I made mirror edit to reflect my issue. I was taught by Codecademy that Function Templates used to return multiple types.  I'm not sure what you meant by deduced.

Comment: Looks like you want a non-template function returning `std::optional<std::string>`. Templates are used to create multiple different instances of the same function, with some types/constants being different. They are _not_ used to make a single function that might return different types under different preconditions.

Comment: You need to show the code that calls this function. The compiler error is from a line of code that is not in the question.

Comment: @cdhowie I want to return a bool (if family members not found) or string (if found). I was taught that templates are used to return multi types

Comment: I'd just return an empty string in the case that there are no family members, but even that seems odd. I'd expect a collection of some sort like a vector so the caller doesn't have to figure out how to split it up and an empty vector would be perfectly natural to return from that.

Comment: @cigien Please see edit.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I used to return "NULL" but remembered about templates, I taught it's elegant to use them, now really want to refactor to templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how templates work.

The *caller* specifies what `T` is.  When `T` is a return type, then *all* return statements in the function must be a `T` value, or something implicitly convertible to `T`.  The function itself can't dictate what `T` is at runtime.

Beyond that, `T` is known *at compile time.*  You can't return different types in different situations without the help of a variant type like `std::variant`.

For each distinct `T`, a *totally new version of the function is created.*  Template functions, therefore, are used when a *generic algorithm* can be applied to multiple types.  For example, a naive implementation of a "swap two values" algorithm might copy one of the values to a temporary variable:

```
void swap(int & a, int & b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

But now we have to write a new `swap()` function for each possible type of thing we ever want to swap!  Enter templates: we write the function once, as a template:

```
template <typename T>
void swap(T & a, T & b) {
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Now the compiler will do the work for us, creating new versions of `swap()` whenever it sees a `T` that it hasn't before.

---

In your particular case, if you want to return a value that might be a string but might be nothing, that's what [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is for.  In this case, you could return an `std::optional<std::string>`.  You could also just return `std::string` and use an empty string to notate that there are no family members.

Given that the name of the function implies that multiple items could be returned, it might make more sense to have the function return `std::vector<std::string>` and then the "no family members" case is simply represented as an empty vector.